# Alguém tem alguma ideia de como montar um sistema de alarmes múltiplos usando a biblioteca WorkManager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, android-alarmmanager

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que funciona como "Alarme" para tomar os medicamentos na hora certa.

Estou tentando usar o repeating do "AlarmManager" para executar esses alarmes. Porém, alguns problemas estão acontecendo:,

1 - **Múltiplos alarmes**. Meu aplicativo permite ao usuário cadastrar vários usuários e vários medicamentos. Sempre atrelando um novo medicamento cadastrado a um usuário existente. Isso é um problema pois a cada alarme disparado, deve-se atualizar um banco de dados internos (Atualização do estoque do medicamento que o alarme disparou).

*Identificar cada alarmManager é um problema para mim. Por que se o usuário quiser interromper o tratamento? Ou mesmo se o estoque zerar? Como identificar o alarme referente ao medicamento e cancelar ele?

Além disso, múltiplos alarmes eventualmente  pode consumir muita bateria, além de que o alarmeManager, pelo que andei me informando, nas versões mais recentes, não costuma disparar no nos horários exatos.

Meu aplicativo é para nível de API 16 e superior e por se tratar de remédios, é de extrema importância que os alarmes sejam disparados na hora exata.

2 - **Reiniciando o aparelho (Reboot)** Um dos problemas que tenho é quando reinicio meu aparelho. Isso porque ao fazer isto, todos os alarmes são extinto.

Para tentar resolver isto, eu uso um BroadCastReceiver que captura a transmição "BOOT COMPLETED" e inicia um "ServiceIntent" que dispara novamente meus alarmes.

Mas o BroadCast Receiver não está recebendo a transmissão de "Boot completed" quando reinicio meu aparelho e eventualmente não executa meu "Service".

Eu tentei de tudo para resolver este problema. DEI A PERMISSÃO no manifest do aplicativo, usei as "action" corretas no fiter-intent do receiver no próprio manifest e iniciei o aplicativo ao menos uma vez antes reiniciá-lo. Mas mesmo assim não consegui com que meu aparelho recebesse a transmissão.

Para resolver isso, dei uma pesquisada e vi que alguns desenvolvedores estão tendo problemas com isso, principalmente com o Android Oreo. Tais soluções para mim não me atende visto que a transmissão de receiver, pelo que andei pesquisando, estão sendo "retiradas" das plataformas androids para evitar malwares e gastos excessivos de bateria (Parece ser uma nova política da Google).

Mesmo que eu conseguisse resolver o problema de transmissão do BroadCast Receiver, eu teria um outro problema que é o ajustes dos alarmes no meu ServiceIntent. Como eu faria para reajustar os alarmes nas horas certas? Isso por que se o usuário cadastrar 5 medicamentos como eu ia fazer para settar todos alarmes de forma independente?

Visto os problemas acima, para mim usar o workmanager resolve eles. Já que eu posso cadastrar vários medicamentos (Através do Work) e separá-los por TAGs para eventual cancelamento. Além de economizar bateria...

O problema é quando se reinicia o aparelho. Porque mesmo o work funcionado depois da reinicialização os horários de disparo dos Alarmes são afetados.

Eu sei que workManager não é a ferramenta ideal para se fazer isso, mas eu quero assim desta forma visto que da outra forma, eu tenho muito mais problemas para resolver. Então optei por tentar assim....

Enquanto escrevi esse post, andei tendo umas ideias. Vou botá-las em prática e se funcionar vou colocar a resposta aqui. Pois de repente a minha dúvida pode ajudar outra pessoa.

Answer (score -1):

Então como prometido, encontrei uma solução para usar o WorkManager como sistema de múltiplos alarmes (em meu aplicativo) e resolvi compartilhar a minha experiência com vocês.

Antes de tudo, embora eu saiba que a função do workManager não é para isso, eu vejo nele a solução de muitos problemas que um sistema de múltiplos alarmes causam no Sistema Operacional do Android. Isso porque, vários alarmes causam um gasto excessivo no uso da bateria (AlarmManager). Já o workmanager enfileira adequadamente cada trabalho e garante a execução. Além do mais, com o workmanager não há necessidade do desenvolvedor criar um BroadCastReceiver para ouvir Intents implícitas (Ação de "BOOT_COMPLETED") e um IntentService para reprogramar os alarmes toda vez que o usuário reiniciar o dispositivo, pois isto o workmanager faz automaticamente. Ele lê a transmissão de BOOT_COMPLETED do SO e reinicia o trabalho.

Então sem mais delongas, vamos a solução.

Recapitulando.... Eu necessitava de um aplicativo que funcionasse como alarme para indicar ao usuário quando é a hora certa de tomar seus medicamento.

As informações sobre o medicamento que os alarme levava em conta para poder disparar eram:

**Hora inicial**

> Ficava ao usuário decidir à que horas iniciaria a administração do medicamento Ex.: 8:33 da manhã ou 17:21 da tarde

**Intervalo entre as administrações**

> Fica ao usuário decidir qual é o intervalo entre as administrações

Outras informações como **estoque**,**data inicial**, **se ativo ou inativo**, eu vou deixar de fora deste exemplo para melhor entendimento.

Continuando.... (Solução)

Observação!!!

Eu notei que por mais que um alarme de medicamentos necessite ser preciso, eu vi que não há necessidade do usuário ter que colocar uma hora tão precisa para iniciar um tratamento. Ex.: 8:33 da manhã ou 17:21 da tarde.

Dai então eu limitei os horários que o usuário poderia iniciar um tratamento para intervalos de 30 em 30 minutos. Veja o exemplo a seguir para melhor intendimento:

**Indique o horário inicial do tratamento**

0:00 da madrugada.

0:30 da madrugada.

1:00 da madrugada.

...

23:00 da noite.

23:30 da noite.

Ou seja, fica limitado em intervalos de 30 em 30 minutos para o usuário escolher o inicio da administração do medicamento.

Fazendo desta forma, eu evito ter que disparar alarmes seguidos em intervalos muito curtos como por exemplo:

5 alarmes diferentes para 5 medicamentos diferentes
(Tem pessoas que tomam coquetel de medicamentos)

1º (17:21) ; 2º (17:22) ; 3º (17:24) ; 4º (17:29) ; 5º (17:30)

O usuário agora só poderá escolher entre esse dois horários (17:00) ou (17:30) para poder iniciar a administração do medicamento.

Fazendo desta maneira, eu criei um tabela em meu banco de dados internos (SQLiteDataBase) chamada "ALARMES_REGISTRADOS".

Essa tabela comporta as seguintes colunas para cada intervalo de horas. Exemplo:

```
//coluna para o horário de "00:00:00"
private static final String COLUNA_000 = "00:00:00"

//coluna para o horário de "00:30:00"
private static final String COLUNA_030 = "00:30:00"

//coluna para o horário de "01:00:00"
private static final String COLUNA_100 = "01:00:00"

//Assim se segue para todos os horários...
```

Essas colunas servem para receberem os nomes do medicamento que iram disparar naquela hora. Ou seja,
se eu configurar um alarme um medicamento de nome RIVOTRIL para iniciar às 16:00 com intervalos de 12 em 12 horas, então as seguintes colunas do meu banco de dados recebem o nome do medicamento.

```
COLUNA_1600 = "Rivotril" // 4 da tarde
COLUNA_400 = "Rivotrl" // 4 da madrugada
```

Com essas informações eu já posso partir para o WorkManager.

Primeiro eu inicio um periodicRequest com o intervalo de 30 em 30 minutos. Isso porque, o tempo mínimo que um alarme pode acontecer em comparação ao outro é de 30 minutos.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                PeriodicWorker.class,30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("VERIFIC_ALARM",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,periodicWorkRequest);
```

E dentro deste periocRequest eu faço o sequinte:

Primeiro eu crio um String[] que contém todos os horários para comparação com a hora atual do sistema em um loop FOR. Assim:

```
private String[] HOURS = {"00:30:00","01:00:00","01:30:00","02:00:00","02:30:00","03:00:00","03:30:00"
            ,"04:00:00","04:30:00","05:00:00","05:30:00","06:00:00","06:30:00","07:00:00","07:30:00","08:00:00"
            ,"08:30:00","09:00:00","09:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00","11:00:00","11:30:00","12:00:00"
            ,"12:30:00","13:00:00","13:30:00","14:00:00","14:30:00","15:00:00","15:30:00","16:00:00"
            ,"16:30:00","17:00:00","17:30:00","18:00:00","18:30:00","19:00:00","19:30:00","20:00:00"
            ,"20:30:00","21:00:00","21:30:00","22:00:00","22:30:00","23:00:00","23:30:00","24:00:00"};
```

Depois eu obtenho a data atual do sistema:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date timeNow = calendar.getTime();
```

Depois eu preparo para devida conversão:

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

Eu converto e faço a comparação:

```
try {

                Date d1 = date.parse(date.format(timeNow));
                Date d2 = date.parse(HOURS[i]);

                long differenceSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());

                if (differenceSeconds <= 1800 && differenceSeconds >= 0) {

                    OneTimeWorkRequest notification=
                            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
                                    .setInitialDelay(differenceSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .setInputData(inputData)
                                    .build();
                    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("NOTIFICATION",
                            ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,notification);


                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Observe que o inicial Delay do OneTimeWorkRequest é a diferença em segundos do horário atual do sistema até o próximo horário de alarme. Exemplo:

Hora atual do sistema - 12:14:30
Hora do próximo alarme (se existir) - 12:30:00

Diferença em segundos - 930 segundos (InitialDelay do OneTimeWorkRequest)

O que basta é eu fazer a manipulação dos dados do SQLiteDataBase no meu OneTimeWorkRequest. Ou seja, pegar os nomes dos medicamentos que estão armazenados na coluna COLUNA_1230 que é referente ao horário 12:30 que é o próximo alarme. Se não houver nenhum nome lá, então nada será mostrado (Nenhum alarme/notificação).

Bom tai como eu fiz e funciona muito bem em todos os emuladores e smartphone que testei. Agradeço a todos que lerem meu post. Infelizmente o STACKOVERFLOW com o pretexto de querer manter a qualidade do site, rotulam perguntas como a minha como "Sem qualidade", em outras palavras, idiotas demais. Pessoalmente, eu acho que isso prejudica demais as pessoas questão iniciando no mundo da programação, porque essas pessoas sempre terão dúvidas por mais idiotas que sejam. Talvez esses inciantes também tenham dúvidas de qualidade, mas que por não saberem perguntar da forma "certa" acabam levando um ponto contra ou mesmo um BAM nas suas contas. É triste!!!

Mas em fim.... Obrigado novamente!!

Comment: Olha cara, não é difícil perguntar da forma certa não viu, assim que você cria a conta recebe todas as regras que deve seguir, incluindo como fazer perguntas, e como NÃO fazer perguntas. É só ler. Boa sorte!

Comment: Já que você lê tudo do site então lê isso aqui:

Comment: Comentário são usados para pedir clarificações ou para apontar problemas na publicação. Comentários desatualizados ou antiquados podem ser excluídos. Saiba mais sobre comentários…

Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Saiba mais sobre formatação…

Comment: Cara larga a mão de ser chorão, se tivesse lido teria entendido, e você está certo sobre os comentários, pode clicar neles e sinalizar para um administrador remover caso não sejam úteis. :D

Comment: Não me sobe nem me desce fazer isso.